# Getting a dataframe from a nested list using dlply/ldply R

Tags: r, plyr

I am using dlply to apply a function to a data.frame and generate a list for each combination of factors:

first I generate some data

```
is1 <- data.frame()
for( s in c("Big","Med", "Sma")) {
 for(i in 1:3){

 c <- rnorm(1,0,10)
 n <- rnorm(1,-1,10)
 is1 <- rbind(is1,data.frame(Site=i,SizeClass=s,d13C=rnorm(10,c,2),d15N=rnorm(10,n,2)))
 }
}
```

them apply the function from siar package

```
require(plyr)
require(siar)
ell <-dlply(is1,.(Site,SizeClass),function(x) standard.ellipse(x$d13C,x$d15N,steps=1))
```

I want a data.frame with some fields so I try to use ldply with a function

```
extract_SEAc <- function(e)
{
  c(sapply(e, '[[', 'xSEAc'),sapply(e, '[[', 'ySEAc'))
}
ell <- ldply(ell, .(Site,SizeClass), extract_SEAc )
```

but it gives an error

```
error: trying to apply a no-function
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the signature:

```
ldply(.data, .fun = NULL, ..., .progress = "none", 
      .inform = FALSE, .parallel = FALSE, .paropts = NULL)
```

`ldply` doesn't take a `.variables` argument like `dlply` (and, it's *not* implied by the `...` as they are passed as args to `.fun`).

Pretty sure this gets what you want (and, I'm fairly sure there are better ways to do it):

```
extract_SEAc <- function(e) {
 data.frame(e$xSEAc, e$ySEAc)
}

e2 <- ldply(ell, extract_SEAc)

head(e2)
  Site SizeClass   e.xSEAc  e.ySEAc
1    1       Big -2.462496 12.28447
2    1       Big -2.473344 12.24886
3    1       Big -2.484814 12.21326
4    1       Big -2.496901 12.17769
5    1       Big -2.509601 12.14216
6    1       Big -2.522911 12.10669
```

Comment: Do you think that there are better ways like what?

Comment: I'd have to ponder it a bit, but I whenever I end up doing something like `ldply(ell, extract_SEAc)[1:2]` (subsetting something like a call to `ldply` post-run like that) it always feels like a hack. This gets you what you need, though, so I'd run with it, provided you grok what it's doing.

Comment: But your answer is not what I intended to do, your results are only the factors, I need the values of variables ySEAc and xSEAc.

Comment: I need the variables ySEAc and xSEAc to be columns of the new data.frame

Comment: like that (modified example)